# json file is overwritten entirely when trying to add an object in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to insert a JSON object in a JSON file (`.json` is located in the `storage/app` folder).

But it's replacing all the previous `data`. My code from the controller is:

```php
public function editjson() {
    $jsonString = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get("test.json");

    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    $extra = array(
        'id' => 2,
        'product_name' => 'Banana',
        'per_item_price' => '50',
        'product_quanity'=> '4',
        'total_price' => '50'
    );
    $array_data[] = $extra;

    $newJsonString = json_encode($array_data);

    file_put_contents("../storage/app/test.json", $newJsonString);
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to see your error... you are retrieving the `$data` but you are not updating it, you are storing your change in a new variable and saving it in that file, hence you are never using the retrieved data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update same array which is retrieved from the json file:

```php
$jsonString = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get("test.json");

$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$extra = [
    'id' => 2,
    'product_name' => 'Banana',
    'per_item_price' => '50',
    'product_quanity' => '4',
    'total_price' => '50'
];

$data[] = $extra;

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);

file_put_contents("../storage/app/test.json", $newJsonString);
```

**Updated**

Instead of using `file_put_contents`.you can use `Storage::disk`

```
Storage::disk('local')->put("test.json",json_encode($newJsonString));
```

Comment: thanks man. you saved my day :) can you help me saying another thing (that will be enough to save my test) : what's the logic to edit an existing json object

Comment: same think .you cant edit json directly, the way is converting to php array or object and updating again to file

Comment: thanks , that means I am updating the entire json file each time I am running this function  ?

Comment: ok . I got it now.  bro you are really amazing - may God make you successful in your life

Comment: Always try to use  laravel built in method instead php because it keeps your code clean